# IFSに改行のみを指定したい

Tags: sh, shellscript

```
$ cat ~/tmp/test.txt
banana 100 abc
apple  200 xyz

$ for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do echo $i;done
banana
100
abc
apple
200
xyz

$export IFS="\n"
$for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do echo $i; done
ba
a
a 100 abc
apple 200 xyz
```

タブ区切りのレコードを１行単位で取り出して処理したいのですが、見ての通りシェルのフィールドセパレータを`"\n"`とするだけでは文字の`"n"`も区切り文字となってしまいます。
意図通りに改行のみで区切るにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。
上記は`ubuntu 15.04`で動作させたため`bash`を使ってますが、できればOS間で共通に動作するシェルスクリプトに応用したいので、`/bin/sh`でも扱える方法が分ると嬉しいです。

利用環境：
ubuntu 15.04
freebsd 10.2-stable
centos 6.7

Comment: 参考情報: [#! Bourne is not bash](http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/bourne-is-not-bash-or-read-echo-and-backslash/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for ループで処理するのであれば、

```
$ IFS='
'
$ for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
```

とします。`IFS` に改行(0x0a)を指定するには改行をそのままの形で入力します。なお、`bash` や `zsh` であれば `$'\n'` といった記法が使用できます。

ここで、`echo` ではなく、`printf` を使う様に変更したのは理由があります。Debian 系 Linux の `/bin/sh`(実体は `/bin/dash`)に限らず、以下の様な問題があるからです。

**test.txt**

```
    banana  \100    abc
-n
apple   200 xyz
```

**echo による処理**

```
$ IFS='
'
$ for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do echo "$i"; done
    banana  \100    abc
apple   200 xyz
```

2行目の `-n` が抜け落ちてしまいました。これは、

```
echo "$i" => echo "-n" => echo -n
```

と解釈されたためです。`printf`(`bash/zsh/dash` では shell builtin function)の場合はこの様な問題は発生しません。

※ 以下は削除


<strike>ただ、一部の sh ではバックスラッシュ文字が問題になります(例えば Ubuntu Linux の `/bin/sh`(実体は `/bin/dash`)。</strike>

**test.txt**

```
    banana  \100    abc
apple   200 xyz
```

**/bin/dash on Ubuntu Linux**

```
$ IFS='
'
$ for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do echo "$i"; done

    banana  @   abc
apple   200 xyz
```

**追記**

Tatz Sekine さんからのコメントで、`/bin/echo` を使うとバックスラッシュ文字はそのまま出力できます(`echo` は `builtin function`)。

```
$ IFS='
'
$ for i in `cat ~/tmp/test.txt`;do /bin/echo "$i"; done

    banana  \100    abc
apple   200 xyz
```

なお、`dash` の `printf`(builtin function)ではバックスラッシュ文字の問題はありません。

```
printf '%s\n' "$i"
```

Comment: dash でバックスラッシュに問題が出てくるのは `echo` 関数の問題ですね。`/bin/echo` を使えばいいだけなので、IFS 変更によるパース処理としては dash でも問題ないです。

Comment: @TatzSekine どうもありがとうございます。ご指摘の点を追記させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

「IFSに改行のみを指定したい」への直接の回答ではないですが、もし入力が tsv なら

```
IFS='    
'  # TAB (^I) と改行 $'\t\n'
while read -r item price comment; do
    /bin/echo "$item" "$price" "$comment"
done < ~/tmp/test.txt
```

という形で書いておけば、カラムごとにパースするのに IFS を戻す必要がありません。

Answer (score 1):

1行単位で処理するのであれば、for ではなく while と read を使った方がいいと思います。

```
(1行を変数に)
export IFS=$(echo -en '\t')
while read -r line ; do echo "$line" ; done < test.txt

(カラムごと変数に:その1)
export IFS=$(echo -en '\t')
while read -r a b c others ; do echo "$a" ; echo "$b" ; echo "$c" ; done < test.txt

(カラムごと変数に:その2)
export IFS=$(echo -en '\t')
while read -r -a arg ; do echo "${arg[0]}" ; echo "${arg[1]}" ; echo ${arg[2]}"; done < test.txt
```

Comment: IFS='\t' が効かないみたいです。無視してください。

Comment: バックスラッシュ文字を考慮すると、`read -r` としておいた方が良いかと。それから、`$line` は `"$line"` としておかないとスペースやタブが約められてしまいます。

Comment: argus さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答を修正しました。
IFS= に TAB を設定するスマートな方法ってあるのでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、、TAB コードを直接入力する以外では `IFS="\`printf '\t'\`"` でしょうか。`/bin/sh` でも動くという条件は結構厳しいですね。 そういえば OpenBSD の `/bin/sh` は Korn シェルだそうです。。。

Answer (score -1):

IFS='^M'

^M = Ctrl+Vを押してからEnterKey
としてはダメですか？